# Testing Javascript in a Rails application with Minitest

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, minitest

I am making a Rails app with some of my views rendered in React, using the `react-rails` gem (so it's using the asset pipeline).

When I try to test my React views, the React components are not loaded, so I cannot test their content. For example, one of my integration tests look like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class TabsIndexTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "index" do
    get tabs_path
    assert_template 'tabs/index'
    assert_select 'table'
  end
end
```

This tests if this index page has a `table` element. It should, but the test is not loading my React element so it does not see one. (However, if I test for the presence of `<div data-react-class=...>`, that passes, letting me know the JS has not run).

Is there any way to get my React components to be visible to my Minitest tests?

Comment: You cannot test javascript with Minitest. I used Capybara with selenium, now it comes default in Rails 5.1. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend *not* testing the components like this in a functional test.

many of the assert_'s are heading out of style in Rails. Really a controller test should only check for HTTP status codes (:ok, :not_found)

More info here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18950

If you really want to test component in this way, you are able to use integration tests with capybara and something like headless chrome to execute the JS

Quick write up here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/headless-feature-specs-with-chrome

I personally would recommend instead using JS unit tests and/or snapshots, which in my experience are quick and friendly:

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html

Answer (score 0):

a very simple solution (instead of using jasmine etc.) was making those helpers:

```rb
  def assert_async_js_equal(expected, script)
    script = <<~SCRIPT
      done = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
      #{script}.then((result) => {
        done(result)
      })
    SCRIPT

    assert_equal(expected, page.evaluate_async_script(script), script)
  end

  def assert_js_equal(expected, script)
    assert_equal(expected, evaluate_script(script), script)
  end
```

then you can do:

```rb
assert_async_js_equal("your_value", "your.promise('code')")
assert_js_equal([1, 2, 3], "[1, 1 + 1, 2 + 1]")
```